# Will Javascript V8 kill all the other server-side dynamic languages? Ruby, Python, PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, python, ruby

That's all. It should be very nice to share the same libs on the client and on the server or not? Are JS VMs like HotRuby (http://hotruby.yukoba.jp/) a "real world" alternative or just a toy?

**PS**: if I ask it is because I'd like know it, please don't close this question but just share your opinion.

- I'm not interested in programming language war. Put some benchmark if you know, or pros and cons
- I'm not comparing apples and pears https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436335/could-node-js-replace-ruby-rails-completely-in-the-future
- I'm not a js fan

Comment: No, it won't. Unless it does. Then yes it will.

Comment: should probably be marked "community wiki"

Comment: **1)** Please don't use URL shorteners when not necessary. I'd like to know where I'm heading for before I click a link. **2)** You can edit your original question and let people vote to reopen it. It's considered bad practice to ask the same question twice. Also read [How do you challenge the closing of one of your questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19126/how-do-you-challenge-the-closing-of-one-of-your-questions)

Comment: @Marcel Korpel tnx to censor me

Comment: Sigh, I was just explaining the way this site works, don't shoot the messenger. You said something like “THE QUESTION WAS CLEAR AND FRIENDLY. DO THE F**K YOU WANT.” I don't think *that* is friendly and I don't like to be spoken to in such a rude manner. If you delete your previous question, the ‘duplicate question’ issue is gone and I (or someone else) will vote to reopen this one.

Comment: Ok I voted to delete the other question -- To allow for possible reopening, you may delete in 2 days

Comment: I can't delete your questions, nor can I vote for it. You can do it yourself or press the 'flag' button to ask a moderator to do so. I voted to reopen (as 4 other SO users did) so new answers can be added again.

Comment: I was under the impression that JavaScript V8 was Google's **client-side** JavaScript engine, which is used in Google Chrome.  Did I miss some announcement about it being used server-side?

Answer (score 12):

Simply put: no.

To use a bit longer explanation: Server-side javascript might put a big dent in currently used scripting languages, but it won't replace them for a few simple reasons:

1. Legacy - there is a lot of code and libs out there already written for PHP, Python etc. Just like nobody is rushing to switch to Python3, nobody will be rushing to switch to server-side JavaScript.
2. Brainfuck - JavaScript is, to most people, still a big brainfuck to code properly. People are used to imperative programming and 'normal' OOP. JavaScript is a strange mix between very weird OOP and functional programming. Not that this is bad, personally I love it, but it turns most mediocre programmers away. And let's face it, most programmers are mediocre.
3. Price - while things running very fast is always nice. People are a lot more expensive these days than hardware is. Transforming everything to a new paradigm, or simply having people learn a whole new way of doing things is just ... expensive. Very expensive.
4. Killer apps - this is related to point number 3. Until there is a very very very good reason to switch to server-side JavaScript people will not be willing to make the investment.

Also, to top it all off, doing server-side stuff is so vastly different from doing browser-side stuff that there is almost no conceivable need for running the same code on both ends. Even the skills required to develop on each end are vastly different.

Comment: If you are looking for the fastest scripting language to write your web frameworks and applications in, you might end up using:

* JavaScript V8 (such as with node.js)
* LuaJIT
* Python with some JIT (like psyco or Unladen Swallow)

However, all these implementations are generally slower than the virtual machines of type-safe managed languages C# and Java. So it might happen that a new, groundbreaking web framework emerges for these languages.

Comment: I've done a view source on various web pages.  JavaScript doesn't turn mediocre programmers away.

Comment: jrockway, yeah, it doesn't turn mediocre programmers away, but they aren't doing things in a javascript way ... now imagine putting those guys in charge of your whole backend stuff. :P

Comment: Things have changed since 2010. Killer app: Node.js. Running the same code in both environments: there's a [move towards isomorphic JavaScript](http://nerds.airbnb.com/isomorphic-javascript-future-web-apps/) that AirBnB's Spike Brehm wrote about, lead by Meteor and detailed in [this Meteor blog post](https://www.meteor.com/blog/2014/08/28/isobuild-why-meteor-created-a-new-package-system).